# Creating a website - what Azure services do I need?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have and website that I host in the my own VPS server (virtual machine).

It has an SQL Server Express database (150mb) and 8GB of product images. I use Bittorent Sync to keep images on my Local PC and VPS in sync.

Since I have 1GB ram on my VPS, SQL takes it all after some time and I would like to move to Azure with hope in better performance.

What services do I need to get from Azure to make this all work. I already got Azure SQL database, but what about website and storage ?

What storage and bandwidth do I need ? It is a bit confusing.

How can I keep storage in sync ?

I live in Europe if that is important.

Thanks in advance

Update:

I want to use Azure Web Role and I need advice about storage.

What type of storage do I need to host my 8GB of images and can I sync it ?

Is there something like One Drive for Azure ?

Comment: There's simply no right answer to this question. There's Azure Websites, Cloud Services with Web Roles (or possibly Worker Roles if you're not using IIS), Virtual Machines, SQL Server in VMs, SQL Database-as-a-Service, and more.

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't post additional details in comments.